# Codificación de caracteres especiales en nombre de archivo MySQL

Tags: mysql

Estoy intentando exportar un archivo de nombre "`ESPAÑA.csv`" en MySQL Workbench y me sale el siguiente nombre "`ESPAÃ‘A_OESTE.csv`". Deseo obtener el primer nombre, he intentado cambiar la codificación de mi base de datos pero igual, usé `ALTER SCHEMA coordenadas_est_base_new DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8;`

Esta es el query:

```
SELECT *
INTO OUTFILE 'C:/ProgramData/MySQL/MySQL Server 5.7/Uploads/ESPAÑA_OESTE.csv'
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
FROM centrales
INNER JOIN coordenadas
ON centrales.idcell = coordenadas.idcell
WHERE coordenadas.nombre_central = 'ESPAÑA_OESTE';
```

Comment: [Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en Español](http://es.stackoverflow.com/tour). Para organizar el código, selecciona el código y presiona [ctrl] + [k]. Mira [esta y otras funcionalidades para formatear lo que coloques en tus preguntas y/o respuestas](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/formatting). Este [enlace](https://es.stackoverflow.com/editing-help) también ese mucha ayuda. Saludos.

Comment: Si ejecutas la query en la consola, ¿el resultado es correcto? Pregunto esto porque aparte es el charset del Workbench y aparte el charset de la base de datos como tal.

Comment: Prueba indicando el juego de caracteres en la misma consulta, algo así: `SELECT *
INTO OUTFILE 'C:/ProgramData/MySQL/MySQL Server 5.7/Uploads/ESPAÑA_OESTE.csv' CHARACTER SET utf8 
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','   ...`  o biennn, ¡no crees nombres de archivo con caracteres especiales!